# What do you call a certain picture in a movie or a music video?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In *The Shawshank Redemption*, there is such a picture of Norton looking

> into the hole in the wall.

> [image]

What do you call this kind of picture depicting certain people or things in a movie or a music video? Is it a shot, a scene or some other thing?

Comment: For a film made in 1994, there's no longer any need for a spoiler alert.

Comment: @Mari-LouA lol who cares what the year is? i suppose there's no problem spoiling alfred hitchcock movies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on context.

If you're discussing film or video technology, each second of film is made up of (usually) between 24 and 60 **frames**. The word describes a basic unit of a film, but isn't the most common term for a still image taken from a film.

A published image taken from a film is commonly called a **still**. Originally this term meant a still photograph taken on a movie set - see [Wikipedia's film still article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_still), but the distinction has long been lost. The point of a still photograph is that it looks like an image from the movie (it usually doesn't include cameras, behind-the-camera staff, etc), but is particularly attractive, memorable, or striking for promotional reasons. Stills were originally better-quality than frames of film, and so were enlarged and used for publicity. Hence the term is commonly used for any image taken from a film which is attractive, distinctive, or memorable. Often memorable images which look like they have been taken from films were actually taken by still photographers. So some people want to preserve the word "still" for the special case, but in practice, it is widely confused or misused.

The term **[screenshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot)** is also used, but it more commonly refers to an image captured from a video game or similar source; this term, and the related **screen capture** and **screen grab**, emphasise that the image has been obtained from a moving image (not taken on set by a still photographer). The term **[frame enlargement](https://www.filmmakersacademy.com/glossary/frame-enlargement/)** is sometimes used for a frame of a film that has been enlarged to make a larger image for study, analysis, etc, but this is more technical.

If a video is paused, the result is commonly called a **still frame** or **freeze frame**: it may be paused to show a significant moment, or just because you're going to make a cup of coffee.

Answer (score 3):

[Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_frame)

You might be familiar with:

[Frame rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) (expressed in frames per second or FPS)